# How to Add User Role ColunmTo Woocommcerce Orders table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can't seem to figure out the PHP code to add a new column on the woocommcerce orders admin page to show the customers user role?

Thanks for your time
Darren

Strugglinjg to get any PHP snippets ive found to work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet you can add to your functions.php:

```
/**
 * Add custom column.
 *
 * @param array $columns Columns.
 * @return array
 */
function set_custom_edit_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['user_role'] = __( 'Role', 'your-text-domain' );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_shop_order_columns', 100, 1 );

/**
 * Add data to custom column.
 *
 * @param string $column Column slug.
 * @param id     $post_id Post ID.
 */
function custom_shop_order_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'user_role' === $column ) {
        $order_user = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_customer_user', true );
        if ( ! empty( $order_user ) ) {
            $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $order_user );
            if ( ! empty( $user ) ) {
                echo implode( ', ', ( array ) $user->roles );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_shop_order_column', 100, 2 );
```

This will only work if you have not opted in for [High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS)](https://woocommerce.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/), otherwise you may have to tweak custom_shop_order_column() method to retrieve data from new custom order meta table.